# Stored Procedure to evaluate column if condition is true execute another stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, case, if-not-exists

I have a stored procedure that executes with Windows task manager and I want to add a condition statement that executes another stored procedure if the condition is true. I was thinking a case statement but I get a invalid syntax near CASE and according to this response executing a stored procedure in a select or case clause is not allowed how would I go about executing a stored procedure on a table if a condition is met.

This is the stored procedure:

```
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 UPDATE Supply
 SET [Quantity] = [Quantity] - [SupplyHalfLife] 

 UPDATE Supply  
 SET SupplyAlert = CASE WHEN Quantity <= SupplyQuantityAlert THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
```

and this is what I want to add to it:

```
SELECT a.SupplyName
CASE a.SupplyAlert
WHEN 'Y' THEN dbo.sp_SendMail @body = a.SupplyName END
FROM Supply a
```

which checks column for a alert status of 'Y' and executes a stored procedure.

Code I finally used:

```
DECLARE @name varchar(255)

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FOR
SELECT SupplyName FROM Supply WHERE SupplyAlert = 'Y'

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    --execute your sproc on each row
    EXEC dbo.SendMail @name

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @name
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886293/how-do-i-execute-a-stored-procedure-once-for-each-row-returned-by-query)

Comment: Great that works, one more thing how would I add a parameter to the SendMail @body = a.SupplyName?

Comment: Is the supply name going to be same or unique ?

Comment: Yes unique to the row with the alert status of 'Y'

Comment: Is this what I need to do [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886293/how-do-i-execute-a-stored-procedure-once-for-each-row-returned-by-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how would I go about executing a stored procedure on a table if a condition is met.

```
if exists (select 1 from Supply where SupplyAlert = 'Y')
begin 
exec dbo.sp_SendMail 
end 
else print 'Nothing to send !'
```

Remember that `CASE` is a function and not a control flow statement.

Comment: Above is correct and worked but I needed unique names added to the Stored procedure which I found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886293/how-do-i-execute-a-stored-procedure-once-for-each-row-returned-by-query)